# Why do folks specify BasedOn="{x:Null}" in a XAML Style element?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I see XAML markup like this:

```
<Style x:Key="SmallSquareButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
```

And I wonder why it is necessary to set the BasedOn property to null.  From the docs, the default value for Style.BasedOn is null. Am I missing something here?

Comment: could this be auto-generated code?

Comment: Possibly, I just tried it in blend and it doesn't do it.  But that's not to say some other tool doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps they are just trying to be explicit? Or they think it is more complete? I know a lot of people who are obsessive compulsive about those kind of things with code.  Personally, I can’t think of any reason why it would be needed at all. If it is anything like I have seen in the past, then one person probably did it for no reason and everyone else in the team just copied paste.